# How to split based on a condition in Apache Camel Routes?

Tags: java, apache-camel

Not sure if this is possible but I have the following POJOs

```
class Item{
  private String name;
  private List<Job> jobs;

  public boolean hasNextJob(){
    //check if there is a next job
  }

}

class Job{
  private String name;
  private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

So in normal "Javaese" I would do something like this.

```
while(item.hasNextJob){
  Job job = item.getNextJob();

  for(Task task : job.getTasks()){
    //process tasks
  }
}
```

I am having some difficulty translating the above logic into an eaipattern. Maybe it doesn't fit a pattern. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are both `Item` and `Job` wrapper classes essential part of your actual problem? I.e. do they carry some necessary information that needs to be taken into account?

Comment: Yes they do carry some necessary information. This is just  a trimmed down example. I went to the Zulip chat for Apache Camel and the devs there suggested to call a ProducerTemplate and start a route myself